# Extract number from txt

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to extract number 26 from res.txt which has :

```
numid=6,iface=MIXER,name='Speaker Playback Volume'
; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=52,step=0
: values=26,26
| dBminmax-min=-52.00dB,max=0.00dB
```

I tried

```
sed -e 's/numid.*values=\(.*\)\,.*/\1/g' res.txt
```

but that didnt work.
Can someone help me with this? I can also use grep or awk to extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using sed

This prints the first value from the first line that (a) follows a line with `numid`, and (b) that matches `: values=`:

```
$ sed -n '/numid/,/: values=/{s/: values=\(.*\),.*/\1/p}' res.txt
26
```

How it works:

- `-n`

  This tells sed not to print unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `/numid/,/: values=/`

  This selects a range of lines that starts with a line matching `numid` and ends with a line matching `: values`.
- `s/: values=\(.*\),.*/\1/p`

  For those selected lines, this prints the first string after the `=` and before the `,`.

#### Using awk

```
$ awk -F'[,=]' 'f && /: values=/{print $2; f=0} /numid/{f=1}' res.txt
26
```

How it works:

- `-F'[,=]'`

  This tells awk to use either `,` or `=` as field separators.
- `f && /: values=/{print $2; f=0}`

  If the variable `f` is nonzero and this line matches `: values=`, then print the second field, $2.  Lastly, set `f` back to zero.
- `/numid/{f=1}`

  If the current line matches `numid`, set variable `f` to one.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to store the value in integer in c++ code by running this command line as system("sed -n '/numid/,/: values=/{s/: values=(.*),.*/\1/p}' res.txt")

Comment: @RDoonds Although c++ is outside of my area, you might look at `popen`.  See, for example: ["How to execute a command and get output of command within C++ using POSIX?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix) or ["How to store system("date +%s) output to variable?c++"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/485134/how-to-store-systemdate-s-output-to-variablec)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the GNU `grep` this can be very easily done with it as follows:

```
grep -oP 'values=\K\d(?=,)' res.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to store the value in integer in c++ code by running this command line as system("sed -n '/numid/,/: values=/{s/: values=(.*),.*/\1/p}' res.txt")